# Implement a 'trending' algorithm to sort a queryset of Posts

Tags: python, django, algorithm

I have a `Post` model for user posts, and also a `PostScore` model to track the score of that `Post` in order to sort the queryset by `trending`, similar to reddit's 'hot':

```
class PostScore(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='score')
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

How would I go about sorting these posts? Would I make a custom method under in `PostScore`:

```
    @property
    def trending(self):
        score = self.upvotes - self.downvotes
        time = self.post.date
        print('TIME:', time)
        return score
```

or would I sort it in my views?:

```
posts = Post.objects.all().filter(entered_category=category).annotate(
    score_diff=F('score__upvotes') - F('score__downvotes'))\
    .order_by('score_diff')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be a good idea to use extra methods of Managers in such situations. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods)